# Confused by CSS pseudo-class :active

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I was looking [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/sel_active.asp) at CSS :active Selector.

> The :active selector styles links to
> active pages

That got me thinking, what the heck is an 'active page' in HTML/CSS terminology...

At this point I went to the [w3docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes) Section : 5.11.3 The dynamic pseudo-classes: :hover, :active, and :focus.

> The :active pseudo-class applies while
> an element is being activated by the
> user. For example, between the times
> the user presses the mouse button and
> releases it.

So I used one of the [w3shools try it pages](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sel_active) and hack together an example, substituting the following code, which you can just cut & paste and try.

```html
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
:focus,:active
{
outline-offset: 10px;
outline: solid;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<p>Click the links to see the background color become yellow:</p>
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com">w3schools.com</a>
<a href="http://www.wikipedia.org">wikipedia.org</a>
<button type="button">Click Me!</button>
<form>
<input type="text"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The form field works for :focus. But the button or links don't work for :active.

Why is that? Is there something about 'active page' I'm not understanding that w3schools talked about.

I saw this [nice tip](http://www.mstudiostalk.com/2008/03/11/pure-css-to-display-the-active-page-in-the-navigation/) when Googling for it, but I don't think it's related.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There is no concept of "active page" in CSS. In fact, the [SitePoint Reference](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-active) debunks this by saying:

> The pseudo-class does *not* signify a link to the active, or current, page—that’s a common misconception among CSS beginners.

What the spec says is right: `:active` simply styles elements that are *activated*, e.g. clicked (as in the example given) or in some other way triggered such that the browser starts navigating to the link's target.

Note that it doesn't just apply to `<a>` elements; it may apply to any non-form-input element that's clicked. For instance, you can do this:

```
p:active {
    color: red;
}
```

And any paragraph you click will flash its text red.

Note however that the exact definition and implementation is left up to the browser, but *in general*, you can rely on `<a>` elements having an activated state.

Answer (score 1):

`:active` is the style given to an element (`a` or a button, for example) when the mouse is held down over it. You might have seen it visible on some sites when you click a styled button; when you *actually* click the button, it might change. This is the `:active` pseudo-class.

Comment: I understood that already. It was the misleading active page thing that w3schools came up with that threw me. Already covered above by @zzzBov &@BoltClock

Answer (score 0):

I've always used `:active` for links. The split second before the browser takes you to the page you just clicked on, the text would change to the color you called in `a:active{ ... }`

Example:

```
a:active { color:pink; font-weight:bold; }
```

Most browsers support it, but it's really not worth your time to style it. Back in the day of 56k dial up it was a nice thing to have to visually show that the link the user clicked was being loaded.