# highlight page link when on page- a:active?

Tags: css, hyperlink, border

I have a portfolio page with a list of clients which when clicked on will display the corresponding gallery- all of this happens on the same page. I would like for the client name to be highlighted when the corresponding gallery is shown. I thought a:active would work, but so far isn't. Any ideas? (If it matters, I'm using Wordpress.)

[live site](http://urbanpalate.com/instyle-mag-ming-by-mango/)

`.active { 
    border: 1px solid #ff893b;
}`

```
<div id="client-list">
<p>
    <a href="?page_id=24" <?php if ($_get['page_id']=='24'){echo 'class="active"';} ?> >H&auml;agen Dazs</a><br/>
    <a href="?page_id=26" <?php if ($_get['page_id']=='26'){echo 'class="active"';} ?>>Hugo Boss Rodeo Drive</a><br/>
    <a href="?page_id=28" <?php if ($_get['page_id']=='28'){echo 'class="active"';} ?>>Ford</a><br/>
    <a href="?page_id=30" <?php if ($_get['page_id']=='30'){echo 'class="active"';} ?>>MOCA Contemporaries</a><br/>
    <a href="?page_id=32" <?php if ($_get['page_id']=='32'){echo 'class="active"';} ?>>XBOX 360 Halo 3 Sneak Preview</a><br/>
    <a href="?page_id=34" <?php if ($_get['page_id']=='34'){echo 'class="active"';} ?>>Saddlerock Smith &amp; Basso Weddings</a><br/>
    <a href="?page_id=36" <?php if ($_get['page_id']=='36'){echo 'class="active"';} ?>>Christie&apos;s</a><br/>
    <a href="?page_id=42" <?php if ($_get['page_id']=='42'){echo 'class="active"';} ?>>Instyle Magazine + Ming by Mango</a></p>

<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
      $('a').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');

     });

    });   

</script>

</div><!-- end client-list -->
```

Comment: [That's not what `:active` means.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5045352/confused-by-css-pseudo-class-active)

Comment: Yep, that's what I've learned. Any ideas on how to make what I'm trying to achieve happen?

Comment: I think your problem is Page Postback when you click a link

Comment: @afshin alright, I've updated my original question again to reflect current code. Again, the orange border shows up while clicking but doesn't stay once everything is loaded.

Comment: $_GET not $_get use Uppercase please for $_GET

Comment: @afshin, changed Get to GET, no changes in function noticed

Comment: your page address should have page_id parameter try yourpagename.php?page_id=24

Comment: @afshin How could I incorporate `<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>` into that?

Comment: I change my answer and test it take look

Comment: @afshin Progress! Now the border stays around the first link regardless of what link I click/gallery I load.

Comment: so your problem is page_id check your url and page_id value

Comment: @afshin page id's match pages & links

Answer (score 1):

```
 <?php
 if (!isset($_GET['page_id'])) {
    $page_id='24';
     }else{
     $page_id=$_GET['page_id'];
    }
 ?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Lab 1</title> 
<style>
 .active { 
 border: 1px solid #ff893b;
 background:red;
 color:white;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="client-list">
<p>
    <a href="?page_id=24" <?php if ($page_id=='24'){echo 'class="active"';} ?>> H&auml;agen Dazs</a><br/>
    <a href="?page_id=26" <?php if ($page_id=='26'){echo 'class="active"';} ?>> Hugo Boss Rodeo Drive</a><br/>
    <a href="?page_id=28" <?php if ($page_id=='28'){echo 'class="active"';} ?>> Ford</a><br/>
    <a href="?page_id=30" <?php if ($page_id=='30'){echo 'class="active"';} ?>> MOCA Contemporaries</a><br/>
    <a href="?page_id=32" <?php if ($page_id=='32'){echo 'class="active"';} ?>> XBOX 360 Halo 3 Sneak Preview</a><br/>
    <a href="?page_id=34" <?php if ($page_id=='34'){echo 'class="active"';} ?>> Saddlerock Smith &amp; Basso Weddings</a><br/>
    <a href="?page_id=36" <?php if ($page_id=='36'){echo 'class="active"';} ?>> Christie&apos;s</a><br/>
    <a href="?page_id=42" <?php if ($page_id=='42'){echo 'class="active"';} ?>> Instyle Magazine + Ming by Mango</a>
</p>
</div>
</body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I'm looking for! Where in the files should I put the java?

Comment: you can put in seprate js file on in script tag in html form

Comment: Again, I'm really very new to incorporating jQuery.
Could you provide an example?

Comment: EDITED: Thanks again for you help. I've made the changes to the css, and tried adding the script to my portfolio.php below my links.. the red box shows up WHILE I'm clicking the link, but doesn't stay once the page has loaded.

Comment: I've edited my original question to reflect my code given your suggestions.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17361/discussion-between-afshin-and-amc)

Answer (score 0):

i think what you need is not `a:active` but instead you should do `a:visited`.

```
#client-list p a:visited { border: 1px solid #ff893b; }
```

html

```
<div id="client-list">

 <p><a href="?page_id=24">H&auml;agen Dazs</a><br/><a href="?page_id=26">Hugo Boss Rodeo Drive</a><br/><a href="?page_id=28">Ford</a><br/><a href="?page_id=30">MOCA Contemporaries</a><br/><a href="?page_id=32">XBOX 360 Halo 3 Sneak Preview</a><br/><a href="?page_id=34">Saddlerock Smith &amp; Basso Weddings</a><br/><a href="?page_id=36">Christie&apos;s</a><br/><a href="?page_id=42">Instyle Magazine + Ming by Mango</a></p>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm still not seeing the orange border around the clients name.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery. When a link is clicked, add a class, e.g., "current" that highlights that link, and removes the class from all the other links (e.g., whichever one was previously highlighted).

I don't think you can do this purely with CSS. The :active class means you are in the process of actively clicking the link; it doesn't persist after you finish clicking it.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. iQuery isn't something I'm very familiar with(yet), could you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

Hey why not use a jquery function like the following for adding and removing classes. It goes like this

Style

```
#client-list a.clicked
{
 color : #ffffff;
/* or what ever style you want */
}
```

Jquery function

```
$(function(){.removeClass()
     $('#client-list a').bind('click' , function(){
     $('#client-list a').removeClass('clicked');
     $(this).addClass('clicked');
   } )
})
```

What query does it strip all the anchor tags from the class clicked and add it only to the current one.
Of course if you add specific click id to each anchor tag you can just save the previously clicked anchor.