# PHP echoActiveClassIfRequestMatches - link not active

Tags: php, echo, nav

I have added this PHP code into my Nav bar to keep the links active when the nav bar links are clicked on. When I navigate to the page via www.something.com the idex.php or home page does not activate

What can I do so when a visitor arrives at my website that that index.php or home page is class="active"

```
    enter code here<?php 

function echoActiveClassIfRequestMatches($requestUri)
{
    $current_file_name = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], ".php");

    if ($current_file_name == $requestUri)
        echo 'class="active"';
}

?>

    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand visible-sm" href="#"><img src="assets/images/all.gif" style="padding-bottom:5px;" alt="" height="35em"></a>
<div class="nav-collapse collapse">

<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li <?=echoActiveClassIfRequestMatches("index")?>><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li <?=echoActiveClassIfRequestMatches("about")?>><a href="about.php">About us</a></li>
<li <?=echoActiveClassIfRequestMatches("services")?>><a href="services.php">Our services</a></li>
<li <?=echoActiveClassIfRequestMatches("contact")?>><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>

        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->

      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `short_open_tags` is `on` in `php.ini`? And your html not valid. You used twice `<li><li..`. Try just `<li <?=echoActiveClassIfRequestMatches("index")?>> ...`

Comment: What do you mean by "keep the links active"? Please provide an exact description of the effect you wish to implement.

Comment: www.something.com does not make home page link active.
www.somthing.com/index.php makes the home page link active

Visitor arrives at www.something.com so will not see the home page link active... how do I get the homepage link to activate

Comment: Again, what do you mean by "active link"? What is an active link? Do you mean a link which is highlighted?

Comment: Apologies, yes highlighted, if link is active the navbar link is highlighted... but if you go directly to www.something.com all the link are not highlighted. if you go to www.something.com/inedx.php or any of the other pages the links are then active i.e. highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

The `:active` CSS class is a pseudo class, ie. a class which cannot be attributed by hand. If you wish to have a link to be highlighted when it corresponds to the current page, you must do it by hand. Your code is fine the way it is, but you have to define the CSS rules to make the link highlight.

Somewhere in your CSS file (or in a `style` section of your html), you need a rule like the following:

```
a.active {
     color: red;
}
```

The `a.active` is the CSS selector indicating you wish to apply the rules within the brackets to the `a` tags with `active` class. You can generalize it to any tag with that very class by removing the `a`. You probably want to replace the CSS rules by ones matching your website style.

See [Confused by CSS pseudo-class :active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5045352/confused-by-css-pseudo-class-active) for details on the `:active` pseudo class.

Perhaps you should also pick a different name for your "active" ad-hoc class, to avoid confusion (maybe "current-page").