# Returning information from PHP to javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have a javascript bootkmarklet that the user can load into what ever webpage they are on.
This then displays a php generated page over the top of the current webpage, this includes some information that the javascript has take from the page the user is on.

What I now need is to be able to have the javascript first run one php file that connects with a mysql database, have the result from the database returned to the javascript which can then call the php file that generates the page overlay.

What I am looking for really is a way for the process to go:

User runs javascript --> javascript runs php for mysql --> javascript gets mysql result back --> javascript runs second php file

Comment: Are you searching for AJAX (Asynchronous Javascript And XML)?

Comment: @h2ooooooo perhaps, I was hoping that this could be added into the exciting javascript however

Comment: This is a slightly outdated example: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

Comment: @HenryFlorence W3schools is a very bad resource! You are not doing the op any favours here.

Comment: @Johan do you have any good examples of using ajax to talk with php and get a database result back, it would just be one string I want back not a whole table etc (so a value in a certain column from a row)

Comment: @Johan isn't that is a matter of opinion, do you have statistics to back that up? I often use w3schools to quickly find information about the javascript dom or asp, it's usually quicker than trawling through irrelevant comments on stackoverflow.com ;).

Comment: @HenryFlorence http://w3fools.com just look at the php sql examples. According to w3schools pdo never happened. The list goes on and on and on.

Comment: @HenryFlorence a much better resource is mdn:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/  see also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120025/will-i-be-downvoted-for-giving-a-w3schools-link  many people on SO will downvote **any** answer listing w3schools as a resource and with good reason. Mdn is the way to go.

Comment: @HenryFlorence check out their javascript they don't use ; but rely on the implicit behavior of the newline. W3schools is like a timemachine. They schould change their tagline to "welcome to 2004".

Comment: @HenryFlorence on css they're often just flat out wrong, see here for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5045352/confused-by-css-pseudo-class-active. I can go on and on.

Comment: @Johan ...I can go on and on...so I noticed!

Comment: Thanks guys these comments where very useful.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a starting point of how to use the ajax features in JQuery.

**Edit - separate javascript file**


**html file:**

```
<html>
<head><title> Ajax test page</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ajaxfunctions.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="ajaxResult"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**js file called 'ajaxfunctions.js':**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#ajaxResult").load("ajaxHello.php");
});
```

**php file called 'ajaxHello.php':**

```
<?php
header("text/html");
echo "hello from php";
?>
```

To read data from a database the php code needs to be a little longer:

```
<?php
 header("text/html");
 $username = "root";
 $password = "";
 $databaseName = "mydatabase";

 $connect = mysql_connect("localhost",$username,$password);
 if (!$connect) die("Connection Error");

 $result = mysql_select_db("$databaseName");
 if(!$result) die("Select DB Error");

 $result = mysql_query("select email from users where firstname='Abbey'");
 if (!$result) die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());

 $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

 echo "Abbeys email address ".$row['email'];
?>
```

This examples looks up Abbeys email address from the users table in the users database and returns it. The Database name, username and password are all set at the top of the script.

Usually the ajax request passes some data from the html page, I am happy to add this code if this helps.

Is this something like what you are looking for?

Comment: Looks good however I would be using it from a separate js file, what changes would need to be done for this for example.

Comment: @ZacPowell Are you running it on a webserver? Generally the webserver loads a html file, which can in turn load a js file. I can separate the two like that.

Comment: I'd love to upvote the answer. It is well written, helpful and answers the question. I sadly am unable to because you're still using the dangerously outdated mysql_ libs even though they have been deprecated for 10 years now. When will people start using pdo? http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: The js files will be separate from the html page they are loaded into

Comment: @Johan ok, well why don't you do something constructive and submit a solution using pdo? ;) Although mysql_query, etc are now deprecated as of PHP 5.0, it won't be removed anytime soon, as half the websites in the world would break, and it does add a clarity to the solution without having to get into OOP.