# Why is my nav ul li:active background color not working?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

In my navigation I want to be able to and click on a navigation link and have the li item change color when you go the page. Eg. I click on the about us tab in the navigation, it goes to the about us page and the about us page tab in the navigation bar has changed color. I tried nav ul li:active but it is not working.

Here is the css:

```
#nav {

    display: block;

    position:relative;

    border: 1px solid #002799;

    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #4970E3 0%, #121B3E 100%) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;

    background: -moz-linear-gradient(to bottom, #4970E3 0%, #121B3E 100%) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;

    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, #4970E3 0%, #121B3E 100%) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;

    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;

    border-radius: 15px;

    height: 40px;

    width: 470px;

    margin: 0px auto;

    font: Bold 16px Verdana;


}

#nav ul {

    margin: 0px;

    padding: 0px;

    min-width:250%;


}


#nav li {

    list-style: none;

    float: left;

    position: relative;

    display:inline;

    width:auto;
}




#nav ul li {

    list-style: none;

    float: left;

    position: relative;

}

#nav ul li:last-child a {

    border:none;

}

#nav ul li:hover {

    background: #060652;

}

#nav ul li:active {

    background: #060652;

}

#nav ul li:hover ul {

    display:block;

    width:100%;
}

#nav ul ul {

    display: none;

    position:absolute;

    left:0px;

    min-width:250%;

    z-index: 999;

    background-color: #4970E3;

}

#nav ul ul li {

    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;

    display:block;

    float: none;


    z-index: 999;

    width: auto;

}

#nav ul ul li a {

    border-right: none;

    font: Bold 16px Verdana;

    width: auto;

}

#nav ul li a {

    text-decoration: none;

    display: block;

    border-right: 1px solid #121B3E;

    padding: 10px 15px;

    color: #fbfbfb !important; 
}
```

Here is the html:

```
<div id="nav">
<ul>
<li><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/">Home</a>
</li>

<li><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/?page_id=12">About Us</a>
<ul>
    <li><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/?page_id=19">Why OSTech</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/?page_id=21">Testimonials</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/?page_id=23 ">Case Study 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/?page_id=25">Case Study 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/?page_id=27">Green IT</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/?page_id=29">OSdesk Intel vPro</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/?page_id=31">Workstation Innovation</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/?page_id=33">Consolidation and Centralisation</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/?page_id=35">The Green Grid</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/?page_id=37">Clean Technologies</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/?page_id=39">OSdesk Remote Management</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a>What We Do</a>
<ul>
    <li><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/?page_id=41">OSdesk</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/?page_id=43">OSguard</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/?page_id=45">OSmon</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/?page_id=47">OSvault & OSclass</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/?page_id=49">OSmail & OShost & OSshare</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/?page_id=52">OStrack & OSdms</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/?page_id=54">OSarchive & OSgroup</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/?page_id=62">OSfaq & OShelp</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/?page_id=56">OSbill & OScal</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/?page_id=16">Contact Us</a><ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: See also: [Confused by CSS pseudo-class :active](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5045352/confused-by-css-pseudo-class-active)

Answer (score 8):

You've misunderstood what `:active` means.

Your web browser has no concept of which `li` on the page represent the *current* page, unless you tell it somehow.

The active selector selects the active link. That is, a link you've selected using keyboard navigation (but haven't followed yet) or a link you've just clicked on (before the new page loads). Once the new page loads, none of the links are active again.

So, you can only use `:active` on `a` elements, and not for what you're trying to do here.

Instead, you want to add a class to the `li` for whichever tab represent the current page, and use CSS to style that `li` appropriately:

```
<li><a href="...">Why OSTech</a></li>
<li class="current"><a href="...">Testimonials</a></li>
<li><a href="...">Case Study 1</a></li>
```

with:

```
li.current {
    background: #060652;
}
```

Comment: The problem with the above method is I have two template files. One for index and one for every other page. I am using wordpress to create the site and am adding the content through its page editor.

Comment: I don't know anything about wordpress specifically, but presumably you can set a variable to the current page, and then conditionally add the class to the html based on this variable.

Comment: Okay I will try using a variable via php.

Answer (score 2):

`:active` is only the action when the link is actively pressed, so you can see it clearly if you click on the link and hold down on it, instead of letting go.

In order to do this you will need to assign a class to the `a` for the page that is open. There are ways to accomplish this with a server-side language so you don't have to do it manually, but if you are making a static `.html` page, you will need to manually add a class (like `class="active"`) to the `a` for each page that is "active".

So for example:

`menu.html` will have `<a href="menu.html" class="active">Menu</a>` and `<a href="about.html">About</a>`

Whereas `about.html` will have `<a href="menu.html">Menu</a>` and `<a href="about.html" class="active">About</a>`

Comment: Can you do this for templates files? Cause I am doing a website using wordpress and the navigation menu is in two template files index.php and page.php(template for every other page except index). I didn't create a separate html page for each website page. Will it work if I add the class to all the links on a template file?

Comment: @user3381910 no, it won't. In WP there is already a class being added to the parent `li` of the `a` if you are using their menu structure (and not hard-coding your own into the `.php` file. If you are hard-coding your own menu into `header.php` of WP, don't.) Because of this, you can simply target `li.current-menu-item a` to do the styling you require for the page you are currently on.

Comment: Damn! I did hardcode my menu into header.php and I don't really want to delete it and redo the menu through wordpress again. Is there another way to achieve what I want if my menu is hardcoded? I will try to do what SpoonMeiser suggested first with variables.

Comment: @user3381910 I think what Aister wrote about `$_GET` for the page ID is the solution for you then :)

Answer (score 1):

Just as everyone said, you'll need to use a separate class for the a, `:active` won't work like what you want.

However, if you use the $_GET['page_id'] value you can set the class automatically. Like this:

```
<li><a <?php if ($_GET['page_id'] == 56) { echo 'class="active" '; } ?>href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/?page_id=56">OSbill & OScal</a></li>
```

You can even go an extra mile, and have the `page_id` stored in an array at the top of the php file. And do a foreach loop and echo out the links as well as class.

```
<li><a>What We Do</a>
<ul><?php
    $menu1 = array ( 41,43,45,47,49,52,54,62,56 );
    foreach ($menu1 as $menu_item) {
        echo "<li><a ";
        if ($_GET['page_id'] == $menu_item) { echo 'class="active" '; }
        echo 'href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/?page_id='.$menu_item.'">OSbill & OScal</a></li>';
    } ?>
</ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the above doesn't work (which it didn't for me) just apply a different colour to your navigation bar depending on which page you are on.

```
ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #333;
}

li a {
display: block;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}

li b {
background-color: green;
}

li a:hover {
background-color: red;
color: white;
}
```

## Use code as above? Simple navigation bar with 'active' faked out.

```
<ul>
<li><b href = "homepage.html">Homepage</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

To extend on what @Aister posted I would not use echo on the html but

```
<li>
   <a>What We Do</a>
   <ul>
   <?php
     $menu1 = array ( 41,43,45,47,49,52,54,62,56 );
         foreach ($menu1 as $menu_item) {
   ?>
       <li>
           <a <?= ($_GET['page_id'] == $menu_item)? 'class="active" ' : '';?> href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/?page_id=<?=$menu_item?>">OSbill & OScal</a>
       </li>
   <?php
       } 
   ?>
   </ul>
</li>
```

The main advantage in this approach is that your templates will be a lot easier to read in your editor because the html syntax highlighting will recognize the HTML and not just see a string.

One caveat to my approach is that you need to have the php ini configured to allow short tags or it will break. If it doesn't work and you can't change it replace

```
<?=
```

with

```
<?php echo
```